# Capture images directly in internal storage

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, internal-storage

Is it possible to Capture images via camera in android by passing uri of internal storage in the Intent? If yes How? I tried in the following way but it gave JHEAD can't read error.

```
File mediaStorageDir = getFilesDir();
File newFile =  new File(mediaStorageDir,IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
Uri newUri = Uri.fromFile(newFile);

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, newUri);

startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of small mistake. You are passing directory rather file name.

Try this way hope this helps you

```
File mediaStorageDir = getFilesDir();
        File newFile =  new File(mediaStorageDir,new Date().getTime() + ".png");
        Uri newUri = Uri.fromFile(newFile);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, newUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```